# Build server for WPF app - does Team City have an advantage over CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: wpf, cruisecontrol.net, teamcity

First off: This is not meant to be an argumentative question or flamebait. I'm genuinely curious about this as I am about to start a build server evaluation process. Also, this question is not a general "which is the better build server" question. There are plenty of those on SO already. I'm wondering about a very specific aspect.

The other day I saw something come across my twitter stream that read something like this:
"If you want to run WPF unit tests, Team City is your best option."

I've done a little bit of digging but I am unable to find anything that backs that statement up. Can anyone shine some light on this, or is that statement pure fiction? If it is true, how does TFS hold up in this regard.

If it matters - we are using TFS 2008 for source control, and MSTest for unit tests. A test library/framework for testing the visual WPF bits has not been chosen yet.

Comment: Did you check out the TFS 2008 buildserver? Just curious..

Comment: We are in the process of giving TFS 2008 a go as our build server. Hopefully we'll have some White tests to try soon.

Answer (score 2):

Wait a minute, he mentions CruiseCOntrol in his title but the tag is for CruiSeControl.NET.
Nothing Kent mentions applies to CrusieControl.NET. I don't know how you want to test WPF, but TFS and MSTest work great on CruiseControl.NET so I'd be interested in where they ran into issues.

So long answer short. No it does not hold an advantage, they both have lots of pros and cons and it will ultimately end up being a personal decision with no right/wrong answer. I myself prefer CC.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I saw probably the same tweet that you did. And I neither remember who tweeted it, but it might have been ayende, in regard to why he built his own buildserver.

I havent done any wpf projects with a build-server so I wouldn´t know if the thing you say about cc.net is true. But If we´re talking automation-tests, triggering button clicks, selecting listbox items, I think it´s has do to with the fact that WPF must run in STA mode while cc.net operates in MTA? or something along those lines...

Comment: If the subject was UI Automation then CC.NET will be tricky because of the fact it runs as a service. Windows services and Daemons if running it on a mac or linux box, are not designed to handle that well. But with a little finagling you can usually get it. If Team City runs as a service/daemon it will have the same issues

Comment: TeamCity agent which actually runs build can be started as a service or via the agent.bat file.